# Pasar parametros entre activities Android studio

Tags: java, android, activity

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una aplicación que tiene login, que usa nombre de usuario y rut para validar el ingreso. la variable rut quiero guardarla, para mostrarla en otro activity, el cual elijo en un menú dentro de la aplicación, en este activity quiero mostrar el parametro del rut en una textview o un editText.

¿que método puedo usar para guardar el parámetro y enviarlo a la clase que abro desde el menú?

Comment: Hay varias formas, por ejemplo puedes declarar variables globales en la clase inicial y llamarlas desde otras clases o si bien pasarlas con put extra en el intent que usarás para pasar de una actividad a otra. Muestra que has intentado y dónde te falla para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Debes agregar como indica Carmen lo que has intentado, revisar [ask]. En el sitio hay bastante información sobre esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sharedpreferences incluso no solo puedes usar SharedPreference, también puedes enviar valores entre Activities : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171257/pasar-parametros-entre-activities-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

Si es para guardar los datos de un login, lo mejor es que uses el SharedPreferences de android, asi guardas en sesión los datos:

```
//Cargas una nueva instancia de SharedPreferences y la pones un nombre
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("miApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Asi guardas un dato (por ejemplo el rut y la id de usuario logueado)
prefs.edit().putString('rut', 'valorquequieras').apply();
prefs.edit().putInt('id', 1).apply();

//Asi recuperas un valor
String rut = prefs.getString('rut', 'valorpordefecto');
Int id = prefs.getInt('id', -1);
```

Al ingresar un valor le das un nombre y le asignas el valor que quieras y para recuperarlo dices que valor quieres recuperar y como segundo parámetro un valor por defecto en caso de que este no exista, asi puedes hacer comprobaciones.

Los SharedPreferences son accessibles desde cualquier parte del código. Espero que te sirva

Comment: Justo estaba investigando sobre eso, muchas gracias, voy a tratar de implementarlo.

Comment: En el sitio hay bastante información de esto  @CobasESP https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sharedpreferences **ayudanos a dirigir a nuevos usuarios para evitar en lo posible agregar información repetida.**

Answer (score 0):

Resolví mi problema, gracias por los comentarios, ocupe SharedPreferences y dejare el código que me sirvió, para que alguien lo pueda reutilizar o solucionar su problema.

//  De esta Manera guardo el valor

```
SharedPreferences guardarRut = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("guardarRut", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor edit = guardarRut.edit();
        edit.putString("rut", rutuser.trim()).apply();
        edit.apply();
```

// Asi recupero el valor

```
 SharedPreferences guardarRut = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("guardarRut", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String userName = guardarRut.getString("rut", "");
    rut.setText(userName);
```